# ViewController lost reference when push notification was being clicked and when the app was in background too

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

1. App is in Background
2. Push notification is received and clicked
3. App will open and be redirect to the SecondViewController and the back button is clicked
4. When click to the back button from SecondViewController and back to FirstViewController the "Menu" loss the reference from MenuViewController

---

5. Push notification is received and clicked

[image]

6. App will open and be redirect to the SecondViewController and the back button is clicked

[image]

7. When click to the back button from SecondViewController and back to FirstViewController the "Menu" loss the reference from MenuViewController

[image]

My Code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        .......
    } else {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];
        self.window.rootViewController = nil;
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

        MenuViewController *menuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
        [navigationController pushViewController:menuViewController animated:NO];

        HomeViewController *homeViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
        [navigationController pushViewController:homeViewController animated:NO];

        AllNewsNotificationViewController *allNewsNotificationViewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AllNewsNotificationViewController"];
        [navigationController pushViewController:allNewsNotificationViewController animated:YES];

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

My MenuViewController impl:

```html
@implementation MenuViewController

- (id)init {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
    
    if (!self) {
        return self;
    }
    
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.homeViewController];
    
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              PKRevealControllerRecognizesPanningOnFrontViewKey : @YES,
                              PKRevealControllerDisablesFrontViewInteractionKey : @NO
                              };
    
    self.revealController = [SubviewPKRevealViewController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:self.navigationController leftViewController:self options:options];
    self.revealController.revealDelegate = self.homeViewController;
    
    // The target view controller must implement this method
    self.navBarGesture =  [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.homeViewController action:@selector(menuPan:)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:self.navBarGesture];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[Configurations sharedInstance] menuBackgroundColor];
    _topView.backgroundColor = [[Configurations sharedInstance] navegationbarBackgroundColor];
    
    return self;
}
```

Menu shortcut (button) from MenuViewController lost the reference and doesn't works.

Comment: Instead of reinstantiating your entire view stack on launch, why don't you just use the Restoration ID property on your storyboard and let the system put it back together itself?

Comment: It seems that your `MenuViewController` should not live within your `UINavigationController`. How are you initially creating your navigation stack? Perhaps `MenuViewController` is the root and it contains your navigation controller as one of its properties? Which library are you using to create your navigation?

Comment: I'm using PKRevealController library, look up at the post i inserted more details about the `MenuViewController`